# Route trafic from one wAP to VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, ipsec, mikrotik, l2tp

i have two mikrotik routers. 
One router - 2011 (main) has public static IP address and has L2TP over ipsec vpn server running on it. I can connect to it from laptops and mobiles. When i connected, my ip changes to routers ip.

The second router 4011 dont have public static ip. On this RB4011 router is running 3 wAPs. Two physical: 5ghz and 2.4ghz. And 3rd one is virtual which is on 2.4ghz interface. I have one bridge which is spreading internet to all three wifi's, virtual has another subnet so its not accessible from physical wAPs.

I want to make VPN connection between two routers, and the tunnel should be spread to only  3rd wAP (virtual). The tunnel should be always connected. So any time when im connecting to wifi 3, i should be under that vpn and all trafic should go through 2011 router. So my IP address should also change to public static from 2011 router.
How I can achieve that?